# How to check the uniqueness inside a for-loop?

Tags: for-loop, go, append, slice

Is there a way to check slices/maps for the presence of a value?

I would like to add a value to a slice ***only*** if it does ***not*** exist in the slice.

This works, but it seems verbose. Is there a better way to do this?

```
orgSlice := []int{1, 2, 3}
newSlice := []int{}
newInt := 2
    
newSlice = append(newSlice, newInt)
for _, v := range orgSlice {
    if v != newInt {
        newSlice = append(newSlice, v)
    }
}

newSlice == [2 1 3]
```

Comment: Re:EDIT - it's the same story for any valid map key type - which string is.

Comment: Re:EDIT2 - if the order of values in 'newSlice' doesn't matter AND it will be used/consumed using a range statement then its construction is redundant - just range the keys of 'set'.

Comment: @jnml Thanks for your comments. I'm storing the list of `ints` in GAE datastore and for the purpose of querying it must be a slice ( `[]int` ). Does that requirement makes my initial technique the better choice? The lists will be small.

Comment: You can avoid the usage of `append()` (and all the reallocations) by creating creating a `newslice := make([]int, len(set))` in the first place. If you do a lot of such "contains the key ..." tests (at least more than 2), converting the slice to a map[int]struct{} will be probably much faster, if you do just a few, looping through the slice directly is probably better.

Comment: @tux21b Ok, thank you, I really appreciate you taking the time to explain all of this.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Your approach would take linear time for each insertion. A better way would be to use a `map[int]struct{}`. Alternatively, you could also use a `map[int]bool` or something similar, but the empty `struct{}` has the advantage that it doesn't occupy any additional space. Therefore `map[int]struct{}` is a popular choice for a set of integers.

**Example:**

```
set := make(map[int]struct{})
set[1] = struct{}{}
set[2] = struct{}{}
set[1] = struct{}{}
// ...

for key := range(set) {
  fmt.Println(key)
}
// each value will be printed only once, in no particular order


// you can use the ,ok idiom to check for existing keys
if _, ok := set[1]; ok {
  fmt.Println("element found")
} else {
  fmt.Println("element not found")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. A couple questions: How would you then recreate the slice? Is there a way to make this strategy work with strings? Sorry if these are obvious - I'm new to Go.

Comment: I would use just the map during the computation (because it has an O(1) behavior instead of O(n)). After that, you can create a slice and copy each value from the map. The elements will have a random order after that, so you might want to sort it. And you can use int, float, struct, string, and arrays as map keys (at least in Go1).

Comment: Thank you specifically for outlining that empty structs don't take additional space.  I didn't know this and would use map[type]interface{} and would assign nil to the interface.

Comment: I was using the map[type]interface{} method as well, doesn't this also not take additional space?

Answer (score 54):

Most efficient is likely to be iterating over the slice and appending if you don't find it.

```
func AppendIfMissing(slice []int, i int) []int {
    for _, ele := range slice {
        if ele == i {
            return slice
        }
    }
    return append(slice, i)
}
```

It's simple and obvious and will be fast for small lists.

Further, it will always be faster than your current map-based solution.  The map-based solution iterates over the whole slice no matter what; this solution returns immediately when it finds that the new value is already present.  Both solutions compare elements as they iterate.  (Each map assignment statement certainly does at least one map key comparison internally.)  A map would only be useful if you could maintain it across many insertions.  If you rebuild it on every insertion, then all advantage is lost.

If you truly need to efficiently handle large lists, consider maintaining the lists in sorted order.  (I suspect the order doesn't matter to you because your first solution appended at the beginning of the list and your latest solution appends at the end.)  If you always keep the lists sorted then you you can use the sort.Search function to do efficient binary insertions.

Comment: "The map-based solution iterates over the whole slice no matter what" - are you sure that this is the way hash-maps work?

Comment: @Ottokar, is he wrong? Many people upvoted but no response left.

Comment: @FilipBartuzi Actually, I think I may have misunderstood the meaning of that statement. Hash-maps obviously don't iterate over elements to find the key, but the "map-based solution" to "append to slice if unique" loses it's advantage if we have to convert the slice to map and then the map back to slice.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/kL5csJT66oh here is the working example

Comment: The map-based solution works if you need to make the call for more than one element. If you're only calling it once then iterating over the slice is fine.

Regardless if you need to 'hunt' for something more than once your data really shouldn't be in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
package main
import "golang.org/x/tools/container/intsets"

func main() {
   var (
      a intsets.Sparse
      b bool
   )
   b = a.Insert(9)
   println(b) // true
   b = a.Insert(9)
   println(b) // false
}
```

https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/container/intsets

Answer (score 1):

This option if the number of missing numbers is unknown

```
AppendIfMissing := func(sl []int, n ...int) []int {
        cache := make(map[int]int)
        for _, elem := range sl {
            cache[elem] = elem
        }
        for _, elem := range n {
            if _, ok := cache[elem]; !ok {
                sl = append(sl, elem)
            }
        }
        return sl
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

distincting a array of a struct :

```
func distinctObjects(objs []ObjectType) (distinctedObjs [] ObjectType){
        var output []ObjectType
    for i:= range objs{
        if output==nil || len(output)==0{
            output=append(output,objs[i])
        } else {
            founded:=false
            for j:= range output{
                    if output[j].fieldname1==objs[i].fieldname1 && output[j].fieldname2==objs[i].fieldname2 &&......... {
                    founded=true
                }
            }
            if !founded{
                output=append(output,objs[i])
            }
        }
    }
    return output
}
```

where the struct here is something like :

```
type ObjectType struct {
    fieldname1 string
    fieldname2 string
    .........
}
```

the object will distinct by checked fields here :

```
if output[j].fieldname1==objs[i].fieldname1 && output[j].fieldname2==objs[i].fieldname2 &&......... {
```