# Can you have a map with no value in go?

Tags: dictionary, go, unique

I ask since I like that maps do not allow multiple keys. I know you can do something like the below where your values are bools or empty struct, but is there a way to get around specifying any value for your keys? Is there some advantage to having to specify an empty struct?

Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251234/go-append-if-unique), but focused on appending only unique values.

```
type N struct {}

func tengoQueCagar() {
    var map_almost_empty_value1 = map[int]bool{0:true,1:false}
    var map_almost_empty_value2 = map[int]struct{}{0:struct{}{},1:struct{}{}} //long and seems like lame syntax...
    var map_almost_empty_value3 = map[int]N{0:N{},1:N{}} //shorter.. better?

    var map_not_possible_empty_value_2 = map[int]nil{0:nil,1:nil} // better than empty struct syntax... but not possible
    var map_not_possible_empty_value_2 = map[int]{0,1} // ideally possible... but not... 

    //do something...
}
```

Comment: A map without values isn't a map--it's a list.

Comment: If you find yourself doing `struct{}{}` a lot, you can create a shortcut variable for it. `empty := struct{}{}; map[int]struct{}{0:empty,1:empty}`

Comment: @Flimzy is this true? Maps guarantee unique keys... that must involve some overhead.

Comment: Of course it's true, by definition. A map is an association of one thing to another. Without "another", it's not a map.

Comment: @Flimzy ok I guess I buy it by definition... I guess I'm asking... are maps and array implementation the same?

Comment: No, maps and arrays (and slices) are not the same.

Comment: And Go doesn't offer any sort of unique slice/array type, so using a map is appropriate. But you still must have the value portion. `struct{}{}` is the idiomatic way to do that. I think you've already got that though :)

Comment: Yeah it just smells in my noob nose. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: Map has performance benefits, as it is hashed. So would still be faster than a slice or set.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`struct{}` requires 0 bytes to store. If you declare a map with `struct{}` values, you'd only be storing map keys.

There's a nice blog post about it: 
https://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/25/the-empty-struct

If you want to use a map like a set, it might help to declare a separate type for it:

```golang
type IntSet map[int]struct{}
```

And you can add some convenience methods to it, such as:

```golang
func (i IntSet) Has(v int) bool {
  _, ok := i[v]
  return ok
}
```

Comment: To add a value to the map use `i[v] = struct{}{}`

Answer (score 12):

For a direct answer to your question: See below!

This "empty `struct{}` as map values trick" comes up often and the argument in favor is always of the form "so the values do not need storage space".

The other natural thing to do is use a `map[int]bool`.

If memory is *really* a constraint of your application (e.g. because you are storing millions or billions of keys in your map) then yes: use `struct{}`. For all other, normal cases: Using `struct{}` makes such map literals awkward and key lookup more complicated as you *have* to use the comma-ok-variant (`if _,ok := m[k]; ok {`.

For bool values you can do a simple `m[k]` which is less to type and is easier to understand.

Personally I think use of `struct{}` as map value is a unnecessary, premature, overly clever optimisation. If you really need to save these few bytes because your map will contain millions of entries then probably a map is not the right data structure anyway: Depending on the use case bit vectors, sparse data structures or even probabilistic data structures (bloom-, cuckoo-filters), union-find, etc. might be much better suited.

**Answer**: No. In a map literal you *have* to specify each and every key. (General rule of thumb: There is no syntactic sugar in Go; there are no clever shortcuts in Go; everything is explicit in Go.)

Comment: One downside of using `map[K]bool` for a set is miss-use where a `false` value is stored into the map. I've seen such maps used as sets where someone adding/editing the code did `m[someKey] = false` instead of `delete(m, someKey)` which of course breaks any code using `if m[someKey]` as a set membership test.

Comment: @DaveC "which of course breaks any code using if m[someKey] as a set membership test." Why? m[somekey] == false in this case.

Comment: D'oh, I got it backwards, the `if m[someKey]` test keeps working but anything doing a `if _, ok := m[someKey]; ok` says it exists but someone doing a `m[someKey] = false` probably intended the key to not exist.

Comment: Yet, using bool value is the recommended way for using map as a set: https://blog.golang.org/maps#TOC_4.